# How to get rid of an index for a website in cpanel

Tags: web, cpanel, whm

I am currently trying to host a website on cpanel. When I try to host it there is an site index on the front of the page. How can I get rid of this index and stop it from rerouting me towards it. I placed all my documents into the public_html. Thanks for any help

This is a link to my website so you can inspect the problem

www.brantleybrennansfriends.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to solve this problem you must name the main file you want to be viewed as index. This creates it the first page and will resolve your problem